# Spectrum of an operator$(Ax)(t) = a(t)x(t)$ in $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $X = C[0,1]$ and define $A:X \to X$ where $(Ax)(t) = a(t)x(t), a\in C[0,1]$

I want to solve problem that similar to this, but I want to understand how to find spectrum of this operator.

I only started learning Spectral Theory, so can anyone help clear up some of the ideas. Any ideas are appreciated.

//I already see other q/a, but it does not help.

Comment: You are only likely to get a similar answer here. You have to tell us which part of the solution you don 't understand.

Comment: But how they find inverse $(T- \lambda I)^{-1}$?